# Find a more simple generator for the following lattice.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, integer-lattices

So i did post the same question a couple of hours ago and it got downvoted(not sure why) and no answers so I deleted it and tried to do my research.

I have the following lattice: $L=\langle(1,2,3),(8,0,-2),(6,-5,5)\rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z^3}$ and I have to find a simpler generator of this lattice. My idea was to write it as a matrix and try to reduce it as much as possible in a reduced row echelon form kind of thing. When I use normal RREF on this matrix I do get the identity matrix, but on nearly all of the steps comes a multiplication with a fraction, which I don't think can be done since we are in $\mathbb{Z}$, and I could't think of any integers operations to do with it in order to simplify it. Does it mean that it can't get any simpler? Is there any other way?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: I think I need to calculate the Hermite normal form

Comment: $(-3,-7,4)$ could replace $(6,-5,5)$ as it's a bit shorter and generates the same lattice. If you have a computer you'd do [lattice basis reduction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm)

Comment: Improving the old question was probably a better idea than deleting it to post it over again.

Comment: @flinty wouldn't an algorithm to determine the Hermite normal form work?

Comment: @GerryMyerson thank you for the suggestion, i didn't know it. I'll keep that in mind for next time.

Comment: @Annalisa that just gives you a decomposition into a triangular matrix and a matrix with det +/- 1 with integer entries - it doesn't produce a smaller basis. If what you mean by 'simpler generator' is 'shorter', as is usually the case with lattice problems, then the LLL algorithm is what you'd try. Edit: it does say 'The LLL algorithm can also be used to efficiently compute the Hermite normal form' on the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_normal_form)

Comment: Assuming the generating vectors are the rows of $L,$   we get the Gram matrix $G=LL^T$ which is symmetric positive definite (unless the supposed generators are dependent).  We can solve $W G W^T = D$ diagonal rational with rational $W.$  The target is to make the revised $G$ as close to diagonal as possible, using only integral  elementary matrices $E$ and letting $G_{k+1}  = E G_k E^T$